# System.Text.Encoding.Default and password encryption

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, mono

Unfortunately, I have some code that does this:

```
            byte[] plainText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ClearText);
            var btcipherText = enc.Encrypt(plainText, btkey);
            System.Text.Encoding en = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            return en.GetString(btcipherText);
```

Which is then saved to the database as a user's password.

In mono, on Ubuntu 12.04, `System.Text.Encoding.Default` is System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, while on Windows 7, it seems to be `System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding`.

The password encryption/decryption code should never have been using `System.Text.Encoding.Default`, but this is inherited code. Looking in `System.Text.Encoding`, and having googled my problem extensively, I am unable to determine how I might decode this string with a standard encoding, and in this case on a Mono/Linux stack that lacks the original encoding.

I've also strangely not been able to find much information on `System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding`

When I try to decrypt a string stored with this encoding, I get the usual "Bad data" and "Invalid block size" Cryptographic exceptions.

Any information or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that there is now data encoded using SBCSCodePageEncoding, and when I am decoding it, I have no obvious choices.

Comment: Existing data is stored as a string, in the database, so encoding is my issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not as clear as I need to be on what my situation is. I still appreciate the effort. The byte[] created after encrypting is then encoded to a string, using the default encoding (the return value above) and that is stored in a varchar field. So when it is read, it has that encoding. And when it is then decoded back to a byte [], it uses the encoding to do so. And yes I can store the string correctly now, say using your method or UTF8Encoding, but there is existing production data that has been encoded with that pagecode crap.

Comment: Using `Encoding.GetString(encryptedText)` is nonsense anyway. It should have used Base64 encoding. Can you change that code?

Comment: You should never store passwords in database. Given that you're encountering problems it might be the best time to re-factor and change it to just store a hash of the password instead of the real password, a simple migration program could decode each password and then hash them and re-save. See Also: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: @Seph - I like that idea, thanks.

Comment: @Henk - yes I'll be ripping this out. I like the idea of merely hashing the passwords.

Comment: @dwerner just be sure to not use the `.GetHashCode()` method, I died a little inside when I saw someone use that for hashing passwords... use something like the methods in `System.Security.Cryptography.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the other answer, given that you know which limited set of encodings are used to convert the byte[] to a string, build a utility (or build it into the app so that passwords are upgraded as they are used) that read and decodes the password back to a valid byte[] then store the byte[] as Base64 in the database.

I see your also considering hashing the passwords, in this case and almost any other case if your dealing with a byte[] that doesn't actually represent text, that you need to store/display as characters then base64 is always a good option.

If you decide to hash the passwords make sure you use a HMAC style hashing system rather than just a plain password + salt, or even better grab a bcrypt implementation for .net.

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would make an app that will decrypt all passwords form database, encrypt them with UTF8 encoding and update the database. Then change the original code to UTF8.

Comment: Encoding random data as UTF-8 will probably fail.

Comment: Yeah, it does fail, unfortunately.